# Currents when converting voltages down

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, ldo

Okay, so I have what could be considered a silly question I should've probably learned when I started working electronics way back when, but I just now thought of it and haven't really needed to ask it until now.

I noticed on a AC-DC adapter yesterday that the ratings going in were 1.5A @ 120V, and the ratings coming out were 6A @ 12V.

So if I was to convert down to 5V, would I be able to squeeze out even more amperage still? Is there a mathematical formula?

I've just never pondered this before or had it explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how the conversion is performed, and broadly there are two options:

- linear converters have approximately the same input and output currents,
- switching converters (and transformers) act like gearboxes, providing a different voltage/current ratio (which is like a torque/speed ratio) but still being limited by **conservation of energy**.

A linear converter drops the voltage across a semiconductor (transistor of some sort), therefore that transistor will dissipate a lot of heat.  If you have a 5V linear regulator supplied from your 12V 6A supply, then it too is capable of only 6A output and the regulator will dissipate $$P = (V_{in} - V_{out}) * I_{out} = (12-5)*6 = 42W$$
and that process has an efficiency of $$ n = P_{out} / P_{in} = (5*6)/(12*6) = 41.7\% $$

For small voltage drops like 1-3V this is a reasonable approach.  For larger drops though, you can see it becomes very inefficient because the efficiency is the voltage ratio.  Say you converted 120V to 12V linearly, that would be 10% efficient; the power supply would dissipate 9x as much as the load!

With a switching converter, conservation of energy means that $$ (P_{out} = V_{out} * I_{out}) \le (P_{in} = V_{in} * I_{in} )$$

Your 12V 6A supply has extremely poor efficiency: $$ n = (6*12)/(1.5*120) = 40\% $$
which leads me to believe that the 1.5A rating is for inrush current, not steady-state operation, or that the supply has very poor power-factor.  It's probably a transformer+rectifier+capacitor arrangement instead of a switching supply.

Anyway, say you had an 80%-efficient switching DC-DC converter, which is not unreasonable.  If you're powering it from a 12V 6A supply and want 5V from it, then: 
$$ P_{out} = V_{out}*I_{out} = n * P_{in} $$
$$ P_{out} \le 0.8*12*6 $$
$$ I_{out} = P_{out} / V_{out} \le 11.52A $$

So yes, you can get more current out by converting down to a lower voltage if you use the right kind of conversion.

Edit: if you're mechanically inclined then think of a voltage = torque and current = speed equivalence.
$$ power = voltage * current = torque * speed $$ 
An efficient voltage conversion process is just like a gearbox in that it allows you to have higher torque at lower speed or vice versa.

Edit 2: a linear conversion is like applying a brake.  It reduces the available output torque (voltage) by dissipating a bunch of power as heat, and doesn't change the speed (current) of operation.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you! Now say I want to do an ac-dc conversion. Is there a circuit and equation to help find out how much power I can get out. Or I guess the equivalent to what you've posted here. Thanks!

Comment: Conversion from AC adds two wrinkles: the need for efficient rectification (google for PFC, or Power Factor Correction, it's basically an extra little DC-DC converter up-front to smooth out the supply current), and the need for safety isolation.  I would not suggest building an AC/DC switching converter at this point, just buy one off the shelf that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you had that adapter at 12V @ 6A it can be converted to 5V.

If a linear regulator were used the current would be no more than 6A and the 5V output. The conversion drops 7V at up to 6A in heat in the linear regulator so 42W is cooking some regulator components.

If you use a suitably designed switching regulator to buck the 12V down to 5V the process becomes more of a net energy conversion minus the loss due to the efficiency of the switcher. So the formula becomes:

((VoltsIn * AmpsIn) * Efficiency) / VoltsOut = AmpsOut

Remember this is with a suitably designed switcher with current capacity ratings that are applicable to the example. So assuming that the switcher was 80% efficient the maximum current you could get out would theoretically be:

(12 * 6 * 0.8)/5 = 11.52A

In this example the 80% efficiency is lost as heat in the regulator components. That would be 14.4W of heat being produced. Substantially less than the linear regulator example but something that would still have to be dealt with.

Hope that helps clear up the subject.

BTW....It is always generally better to start with a AC to DC adapter that produces the target voltage that you need than to do a double stage conversion. The properly designed adapter with the components available today can get close to 95% efficiency.

Comment: Brillant. Thank you. And I know about using Vin closer to Vout, but I needed higher voltages for other stuff onboard too, and this was the best solution I could find for consumer use

Comment: Now say I want to do an ac-dc conversion. Is there a circuit and equation to help find out how much power I can get out. Or I guess the equivalent to what you've posted here. Thanks!

Comment: @DominicLuciano - For almost all cases you are far better off purchasing a ready made AC-to-DC conversion power supply. Only reason you would not be doing that is because you are wanting to try to compete in an already crowded marketplace.

Comment: No I get that. It's just because I'd like to know the equivalent equation for AC-DC conversion.